# Ionic 5 Capacitor - Firebase Analytics only works on Web

Tags: javascript, firebase, ionic4, firebase-analytics, capacitor

I am trying to enable Firebase Analytics in my Ionic 5/Capacitor app for Android. When I test it locally, using `ionic serve --lab` (running on the browser), everything is working perfectly, all my data is collected in Firebase.

However, when I launch my app on Google Play and install it on my phone, no data is collected.

Here my code:

**MainActivity.java**

```
import com.getcapacitor.community.firebaseanalytics.FirebaseAnalytics;

public class MainActivity extends BridgeActivity {
  @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

      // Initializes the Bridge
      this.init(savedInstanceState, new ArrayList<Class<? extends Plugin>>() {{
        add(GoogleAuth.class);
        add(FirebaseAnalytics.class);
      }});
    }
}
```

**analytics.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { environment } from './../../environments/environment';
import { Router, RouterEvent, NavigationEnd } from '@angular/router';
import { filter } from 'rxjs/operators';
import '@capacitor-community/firebase-analytics';
import { Plugins } from '@capacitor/core';
import { AuthService } from './auth.service';
import { AngularFireAuth } from '@angular/fire/auth';
const { FirebaseAnalytics, Device } = Plugins;

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AnalyticsService {
  analyticsEnabled = true;

  constructor( private router: Router, public authService: AuthService, public afAuth: AngularFireAuth) {
    this.initFb();
    this.router.events.pipe(
      filter((e: RouterEvent) => e instanceof NavigationEnd),
    ).subscribe((e: RouterEvent) => {
      console.log('route changed: ', e.url);
      this.setScreenName(e.url);
    });
    this.setUser();
  }

  async initFb() {
    if ((await Device.getInfo()).platform === 'web') {
      FirebaseAnalytics.initializeFirebase(environment.firebaseConfig);
      console.log('Firebase Analytics init!');
    }
  }

  setUser() {
    // Use Firebase Auth uid
    this.afAuth.authState.subscribe(user => {
      FirebaseAnalytics.setUserId({
          userId: user.uid
      });
      console.log(user.uid);
    });
  }

  setProperty() {
    FirebaseAnalytics.setUserProperty({
      name: 'framework',
      value: 'angular',
    });
  }

  logEvent() {
    FirebaseAnalytics.logEvent({
      name: 'login',
      params: {
        method: 'email'
      }
    });
  }

  setScreenName(screenName) {
    FirebaseAnalytics.setScreenName({
      screenName
    });
  }

  toggleAnalytics() {
    this.analyticsEnabled = !this.analyticsEnabled;
    FirebaseAnalytics.setCollectionEnabled({
      enabled: this.analyticsEnabled,
    });
  }

}
```

**app.module**

```
import { AnalyticsService } from './services/analytics.service';

providers: [
    AuthGuard,
    AuthService,
    AnalyticsService,
    ...
  ]
```

**home.page.ts**

```
import { AnalyticsService } from '../services/analytics.service';
```

Is something missing to work on Android devices?

Comment: @SurajRao Do I need to initialize in all platforms?

Comment: basically `FirebaseAnalytics.initializeFirebase` is never executed in your device as platform would be 'android'... Try removing the condition and running your app in a device.

Comment: @SurajRao It still doesn't work. There must be something missing. Maybe some permission?

Comment: From the docs `FirebaseAnalytics.initializeFirebase` is only for web as it turns out... Do you get any errors ?

Comment: [This](https://github.com/priyankpat/capacitor-plugins-example/tree/firebase-analytics) is a linked example given in their [github](https://github.com/capacitor-community/firebase-analytics). Perhaps comapre with your code?

Comment: Yep, the `FirebaseAnalytics.initializeFirebase` is only for the web, and it works on web platform. In the other file, I mean in **MainActivity.java**, my code is the same as the link you mentioned. The only difference is about the way I call the functions (using a service and import it into my home page). No errors...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239905/discussion-between-atoyansk-and-suraj-rao).